# Using metadata in formula in Apex

Tags: apex, batch, formula, schedulebatch, custom-metadata

I was working on a bank management App. and as a feature, I created a batch that is supposed to do a deposit regularly every three months. And the requirement was that I use a custom metadata for the percent of deposit being done. But I'm failing to do so with the code below. Can someone help me with this?

```
public class interestTransaction implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id, Balance__C FROM Bank_Account__c');
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Bank_Account__c> scope){
      
        List<Transaction__c> transactions = new List<Transaction__c>();
        Interest_Rate__mdt ir = [SELECT Interest_rate__c FROM Interest_Rate__mdt]; 
        
        for(Bank_Account__c trans : scope){
            Decimal amount = trans.Balance__c * ir;
            Transaction__c tran  = new Transaction__c();
            tran.Type__c = 'Deposit'; 
            tran.Bank_Account__c = trans.Id;
            tran.Amount__c = amount ;
            transactions.add(tran);
            }
         insert transactions;
    
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
    public void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        interestTransaction interestTransactionInstance = new interestTransaction();
        Database.executeBatch(interestTransactionInstance);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is here:

```
    Decimal amount = trans.Balance__c * ir;
```

You're trying to multiply a *record* against a *number*. This is not allowed. You probably meant:

```
    Decimal amount = trans.Balance__c * ir.Interest_rate__c;
```

Comment: solved my problem. Thanks!